# Captured image does not show up in imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera-intent

I already did a precisely search to solve my problem, but unfortunately none of the provided solutions solved my problem. My problem is that the captured image does not show up in the imageview. I tried to modify the onActivityResult() method, but still it won't work.

Here is my complete **Activity** class wich calls the camera intent:

```
    public class EditProfileActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * JSON Response node names.
     **/
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_RESIDENCE = "residence";

    TextView inputfname, inputlname, inputemail;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;
    AutoCompleteTextView inputresidence;
    ImageView imgFavorite;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile_layout);

        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });



        // actionBar = getActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user = db.getUserDetails();

        inputfname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputlname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputresidence = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);

        // inputfname.setText("");
        inputfname.setText(user.get("fname"));
        inputlname.setText(user.get("lname"));
        inputemail.setText(user.get("email"));
        inputresidence.setText(user.get("residence"));

        inputresidence = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        inputresidence.setThreshold(1);

        inputresidence.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                //imageView.invalidate();
            }  
        }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";
            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
            String key = "key=AIzaSyDP-e-LqaAQ5NsJMffT68ed5o0ZnpyHG_c";
            String input = "";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            try {
                // Fetching the data from we service
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
            parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

            // Setting the adapter
            inputresidence.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProfileActivity.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {

            /**
             * Gets current device state and checks for working internet
             * connection by trying Google.
             **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th) {

            if (th == true) {
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessUpdateProfile().execute();
            } else {
                nDialog.dismiss();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error in Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ProcessUpdateProfile extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String uid, fname, lname, email, residence;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            // Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database

            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            user = db.getUserDetails();
            uid = user.get("uid");
            fname = inputfname.getText().toString();
            lname = inputlname.getText().toString();
            email = inputemail.getText().toString();
            residence = inputresidence.getText().toString();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProfileActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Server");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registrierung..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

            JSONObject json = userFunction.updateProfile(uid, fname, lname,
                    email, residence);

            return json;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    // registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    // inputEmail.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // inputUsername.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        pDialog.setTitle("Daten");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Laden..");

                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_UID),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_RESIDENCE));

                        // json_user.getString(KEY_LAST_LOGIN));

                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database Launch
                         * Registered screen
                         **/

                        /*
                         * Intent dashboard = new
                         * Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         * ProfileFragment.class);
                         */

                        pDialog.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ihre Daten wurden erfolgreich aktualisiert!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER
                                | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(red) == 2) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        inputemail.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "E-Mail existiert bereits!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        // registerErrorMsg.setText("E-Mail existiert bereits");

                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(red) == 3) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        inputemail.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ungültige E-Mail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // registerErrorMsg.setText("Ungültige E-Mail");
                    }
                }

                else {
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Fehler aufgetreten, bitte nochmal versuchen",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_profile_save, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_save:

            if ((!inputfname.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!inputlname.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!inputemail.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    && (!inputresidence.getText().toString().equals(""))) {

                NetAsync(item);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Bitte alle Felder füllen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    public void NetAsync(MenuItem item) {
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        this.onCreate(null);
    }
}
```

And here is the associated **xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditProfileActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_change_profilePic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:hint="@string/text_change_avatar" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="take image" >
        </Button>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="test"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_change_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:hint="@string/btn_upload_avatar" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:hint="@string/EditText_firstname"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:hint="@string/EditText_lastname"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:hint="@string/EditText_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <com.Sinan_Kalkan.sinis.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/atv_places"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/EditText_residence"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

***********UPDATE:**
 **SOLVED MY PROBLEM BY DELETING FOLLOWING METHOD IN MY ACTIVITY CLASS:**

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        this.onCreate(null);
    }
```

Obviously the method onResume() caused the problem. Thanks anyways for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Button bt_camera=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt_camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        // ******** code for crop image
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

        try {

        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Do nothing for now
        }
```

onResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
try
{
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    System.out.println("frome the PICK_FROM_CAMERA ");
    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
    img.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
catch(NullPointerException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Canclled", 3000).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately your provided code throws me a NullPointerException. I use genymotion emulator, and the camera preview is always in landscape, maybe this is a hint why the preview on imageview is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
private String imgPath;

public Uri setImageUri() {
  // Store image in dcim
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new     Date().getTime() + ".png");
  Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
  return imgPath;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
   try {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale = 1;
    while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
    scale *= 2;
        // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
     } catch (Throwable e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
  return null;
}

photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);     
    }
});


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
       switch (requestCode) {
       case CAMERA_REQUEST:
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                     
           Bitmap photo = decodeFile(getImagePath);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);                              
       }
       break;
       default:
       break;
     }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You may have to give the path where your taken image should be stored.. If you used this, then you can use the same path for displaying the image..

Kindly find the below code for taking picture:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File photo = new File("sd card path where should be stored"
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("exit", "false");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
```

You may have to give permission in manifest for using camera, reading and writing permission for sdcard.. then in your onActivityResult based on the request code you can show the image from that path..

Kindly let me know if you have any queries